# Couchbase executing query is very slow

Tags: ios, swift, performance, couchbase, couchbase-lite

We use Couchbase and CBL for over 3 years now and one thing always bothered. When we execute queries to read entries from expressions over keys, the execution of the Couchbase query is decreasing the performance of our apps significantly. E. g. we have 25000 data entries with relatively small documents in our CBL. Reading 100 of these entries takes 0.5 seconds which is unacceptable for our application. The documents contain only very small JSON documents. We could theoretically read all the data into objects once at the start of the database to execute only one query and manage data in Swift documents which we actually did a while ago but this is not the idea of a local database if I am not mistaking, it would make the CBL pretty much useless. Is there anything we miss about building the query or general Couchbase? How can we read the data faster?

I am writing here hoping that we miss something about Couchbase because executing these queries with SQL seems much faster. The execution time I mention is of course different on different devices but on every device I use it is approximately half a second and this is much too slow for 100 entries

Time different tasks consume
(1) Takes 0.5 seconds
(2) Takes 0.0001 seconds
Running multiple of such queries takes forever

Here the code we use in Swift:

```
       let ourDocumentKeyPrefix = "SomeKeyPrefix"
       let query = QueryBuilder
            .select(
                SelectResult.all(),
                SelectResult.expression(Meta.id)
            )
            .from(DataSource.database(database!))
            .where(Meta.id.like(Expression.string(\(ourDocumentKeyPrefix)::%"))
        )


        do {
            for result in try query.execute() {  **//(1)** executing Couchbase query

                   **//(2)** my extraction data code here....
            }
        } catch {

        }
```

I am currently using the pod CouchbaseLite-Swift (2.7.0) but we had the problem with previous versions too

Answer (score 3):

*Couchbase Lite architect here...*

This query is slow because **LIKE comparisons aren't optimized by indexes in Couchbase Lite**, so the query has to scan through every document in the database and apply the LIKE test. You can verify this by looking at the query's `explanation` property, which will show various info including a summary of what index(es) are used. **The `explanation` property is your best tool when you're trying to optimize a query.**

(In general a LIKE comparison of this kind, which is a prefix match, ought to be indexable. And it is, in default SQLite. But Couchbase Lite installs a custom LIKE function, since the default one doesn't support case-folding or I18N, and once that happens SQLite will no longer use the prefix-match optimization since it no longer knows the exact semantics of LIKE.)

It doesn't help that there's an unfortunate bug in 2.7.0 that slowed down LIKE; the fix is in 2.7.1 (which is either out now or will be very soon.)

**The best workaround is to replace LIKE with an explicit prefix test**, such as (in N1QL syntax) `meta.id >= $keyPrefix || "::" AND meta.id < $keyPrefix || ":;"` -- note the semicolon, which is the next character after a colon in the sort order.